# How do I identifying the first zero in a group of ordered columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, survival

I'm trying to format a dataset for use in some survival analysis models. Each row is a school, and the time-varying columns are the total number of students enrolled in the school that year. Say the data frame looks like this (there are time invariate columns as well).

```
Name   total.89   total.90   total.91   total.92 
a         8          6         4           0
b         1          2         4           9
c         7          9         0           0
d         2          0         0           0
```

I'd like to create a new column indicating when the school "died," i.e., the first column in which a zero appears. Ultimately I'd like to have this column be "years since 1989" and can re-name columns accordingly.

A more general version of the question, for a series of time ordered columns, how do I identify the first column in which a given value occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a base R approach to get a column with the first zero (`x = 0`) or `NA` if there isn't one:

```
data$died <- apply(data[, -1], 1, match, x = 0)
data
#   Name total.89 total.90 total.91 total.92 died
# 1    a        8        6        4        0    4
# 2    b        1        2        4        9   NA
# 3    c        7        9        0        0    3
# 4    d        2        0        0        0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `max.col` with `rowSums`

```
df1$died <- max.col(!df1[-1], "first") * NA^!rowSums(!df1[-1])
df1$died
#[1]  4 NA  3  2
```